# Declare set in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

trying to create a declare set statement in Oracle SQL Developer adding dates. Checked similar discussions but couldn't find the correct solution.

Getting an error for the following statement:

```
declare or define
Date1 date := to_date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
Date2 date := to_date('2018-01-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
begin

    select......
    from.....
    where....

end
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
select .....
from .....
where activity >= Date1
and activity  < Date2
```

Thanks

Comment: *Getting an error for the following statement* but you didn't mentioned what ?

Comment: Please post yout exact code and the error you've got

Comment: Hi, here the error: ORA-06550: line 45, column 2:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 46, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: How can people find an error without seeing the code?

Comment: What is a "declare set statement"? I've never heard of that.

Answer (score 0):

Line 45? Consider posting your whole code, it is difficult to debug code you can't see.

Apart from that, DECLARE section you used is OK. However, you might be missing the INTO clause, as PL/SQL requires it. Something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    date1 date := to_Date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  3    date2 date := to_Date('2018-01-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  4    l_cnt number;   --> you might be missing this ...
  5  begin
  6    select count(*)
  7      into l_cnt    --> ...  and this
  8      from employees
  9      where hire_date >= date1
 10        and hire_date < date2;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Anyway: edit your initial message and copy/paste **exactly** what you have, otherwise we're just blindly guessing.